# Why failed to add item on a session IEnumerable list

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Work on entity framework vs2010,
I want to store somewhere some set of objects obtained from the database. Because I dont want to call DB after which user request. And I do it this way:

```
public IEnumerable<Message> Messages {
    get { return HttpContext.Session[SESSION_MESSAGES_NAME] as IEnumerable<Message>; }
    set { HttpContext.Session[SESSION_MESSAGES_NAME] = value; }
}

objEntity = new CmnItemSpecificationDetail();
                objEntity.ItemSpecificationDetailRecordID = hidItemSpecificationDetailRecordID.Value.ToString() == "" ? _ItemSpecificationDetail.Count + 1 : int.Parse(hidItemSpecificationDetailRecordID.Value.ToString());
                objEntity.SpecificationID = drpSpecification.SelectedIndex == 0 ? -1 : int.Parse(drpSpecification.SelectedValue);
                objEntity.SpecValue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSpecValue.Text);
                objEntity.UOMID = drpUOM.SelectedIndex == 0 ? -1 : int.Parse(drpUOM.SelectedValue);
                objEntity.UOMID = 1;


                objEntity.Action = Entity.ActionMode.Add;
                objEntity.Action = Entity.ActionMode.Add;
                objEntity.CreateBy = LogInUser;
                objEntity.CreateOn = DateTime.Now;
                objEntity.CreatePc = PCName;
                Messages.Append(objEntity);//failed to add item




  public static class exten
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, params T[] items)
        {
           return source.Concat(items);

        }
    }
```

This list failed to  fill up  item,want to know why this can not add item on list,what is the problem,How to solve this problem.

If have any query please ask ,thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to modify your Getter a bit.

The way it currently works it doesn't handle situations where the Messages is null (hasn't been initialized).

Change this

```
 get { return HttpContext.Session[SESSION_MESSAGES_NAME] as IEnumerable<Message>; }
```

To this.

```
 get { var msg = HttpContext.Session[SESSION_MESSAGES_NAME] as IEnumerable<Message>;
      if(msg == null) {
          msg = new List<Message>();
         HttpContext.Session[SESSION_MESSAGES_NAME] = msg;
       }

       return msg;

    }
```

Comment: scartag,Thanks for reply,
Your get syntax show me error message:
Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or
 interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<XERP.CMN.EntityModel.CmnItemSpecificationDetail>'

Comment: @shamim We could modify it to be an implementation of IEnumrable .. like a List<T> will modify my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Append()` extension method does NOT change the original sequence. It returns a new sequence with the specified items appended to it.

When you call `Messages.Append(objEntity)`, you don't do anything with the return value, so you are throwing away the results of the Append().

To fix it, you will need to do something with the return value. Perhaps just do:

```
Messages = Messages.Append(objEntity);
```